# Restful service naming conventions?

Tags: java, rest

For a restfull service, does the noun can be omitted and discarded?

Instead of `/service/customers/555/orders/111`

Can / should I expose: `/service/555/111` ?

Is the first option mandatory or are there several options and this is debatable?

Comment: It is totally up you AFAIK.  If you find the names in the path make it easier to see what is being called, then leave them there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the core aspects of REST is that URLs should be treated as opaque entities. A client should **never create a URL**, just **use URLs** that have been supplied by the server. Only the server hosting the entities needs to know something about the URL structure.

So use the URL scheme that makes most sense to you when designing the service.

Regarding the options you mentioned:

- Omitting the nouns makes it hard to extend your service if e.g. you want to add products, receipts or other entities.
- Having the orders below the customers surprises me (but once again, that's up to you designing the service). I'd expect something like `/service/customers/555` and `/service/orders/1234567`.

Anyway, the RESTful customer document returned from the service should contain links to his or her orders and vice versa (plus all other relevant relationships).

Answer (score 3):

It's totally up to you, I think the nice thing about having the nouns is that it helps you see from the URL what the service is trying to achieve.

Also taking into account that under customer you can have something like below and from the URL you can distinguish between order and quote for a customer

- /service/customers/555/quote/111
- /service/customers/555/order/111

Answer (score 2):

To a certain degree, the "rules" for nameing RESTful endpoints should follow the same naming rules that "Clean Code" for example teaches.

Meaning: names should mean something. And they should say what they mean, and mean what they say.

Coming from there: it probably depends on the *nature* of that service. If you only can "serve" customers - then you could omit the *customer* part - because that doesn't add (much) meaningful information. But what if you later want to serve *other* kinds of clients?

In other words: we can't tell you what is right for your application - because that depends on the requirements / goals of your environment.

And worth noting: do not only consider todays *requirements*. Step back and consider those "future grow paths" that seem most likely. And then make sure that the API you are defining today will work nicely with those future extensions that are most likely to happen.

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of /service/customers/555/orders/111
>
> Can / should I expose: /service/555/111 ?

The question is broad but as you use REST paths to define nested information, that has to be as much explicit as required.
If providing long paths in the URL is a problem for you, as alternative provide the contextual information in the body of the request.

I think that the short way `/service/555/111`  lacks consistency.

Suppose that `/service/555/111` correspond to invoke the service for the customer `555` and the order `111`. 
You know that. But the client of the API doesn't know necessarily what the paths meaning are.

Besides, suppose now that you wish invoke the invoke the same service for the customer `555` but for the year `2018`. How do that now ?
Like that : 
 `/service/555/2018` would be error prone as you will have to add a parameter to convey the last path value and  `service/555/years/2018` will make your API definition inconsistent.

Clarity, simplicity and consistency matters.

Answer (score 1):

According to me usage of noun is not necessary or comes under any standard,but yes it's usage helps your endpoint to be more specific and simple to understand.

So if any nomenclature is making your URL more human readable or easy to understand then that type or URL I usually prefer to create and keep things simple. It also helps your service consumer who understand the functionality of any service partially by name itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/  for the best practices.

Answer (score 0):

> For a restfull service, does the noun can be omitted and discarded?

Yes.  REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your resource identifiers.

URL shorteners *work* just fine.

Choices of spelling are dictated by local convention, they are much like variables in that sense.

Ideally, the spellings are independent of the underlying domain and data models, so that you can change the models without changing the api.  Jim Webber expressed the idea this way

> The web is not your domain, it's a document management system.  All the HTTP verbs apply to the document management domain. URIs do NOT map onto domain objects - that violates encapsulation.  Work (ex: issuing commands to the domain model) is a side effect of managing resources.  In other words, the resources are part of the anti-corruption layer.  You should expect to have many many more resources in your integration domain than you do business objects in your business domain.
>
> Resources adapt your domain model for the web

That said, if you are expecting clients to discover URIs in your documentation (rather than by reading them out of well specified hypermedia responses), then its going to be a good idea to use URI spellings that follow a simple conceptual model.